# how to make "choose file" function on windows programming?

Tags: c++, windows

I need this us all known "choose file" feature in my program, so i can load files.

What is this thing called as and where is the code for it?

Comment: Are you using a GUI framework of some kind, or just plain Win32 API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are referring to are the ["common dialogs"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645524%28VS.85%29.aspx), and you can get a file open dialog with [GetOpenFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646927%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
BOOL GetOpenFileName(      
    LPOPENFILENAME lpofn
);
```

[A sample is available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646829%28VS.85%29.aspx#open_file)

Answer (score 2):

With plain Win32 API you need to use the `GetOpenFileName`  function, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646927%28VS.85%29.aspx). An example of its usage is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646829%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to know about the built-in Windows dialog for choosing/opening a file.

If you're doing managed code, see [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx).

If you're doing MFC, see [CFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk77e5e7(VS.80).aspx).