# Get one file's name method - Customize the interface - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, button, interface

I'm looking for some guide for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, but I can't find nothing useful.
I'm coding in c++.
What I need is to create a button (in the dialog box) that, when I click on it, gives me the possibility to choose a file from my pc. 
After that, I only need to charge in memory (like in a string variable nameFile) the name of this file.
Do anyone know how to do this operation?

And second problem, do you guys know any youtube guide or similar to customize the interface??
Like to put one picture on the background of the application, or change button style etc.
I used Eclipse before, coding in Java and It was totally different.

Thank you all!!

Comment: C++ and UI.  Are you using MFC?  Is a reason you cannot use an easier language, more up-to-date language for doing this, e.g., C#?

Comment: @MattDavis why is C# **more up-to-date language** comparing to c++?

Comment: I have nothing against C++, but it would be one of my **last** choices for UI development.

Comment: Yeah, the reason is that I never learnt C# :) so...I need to do it in C++.
I need it to complete the code of a video on demand system and it's all in C++.

Comment: c++ is absolutely fine for creating GUIs under windows or most any other OS. What framework are you using? MFC?

Comment: yep, using MFC.
And it's the first time a use Visual Studio, so I'm not an expert :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make "choose file" function on windows programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167922/how-to-make-choose-file-function-on-windows-programming)

Comment: You want to start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk77e5e7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx There is even an example.

Comment: BTW, When I read this question I thought you were looking for the name of the application. And I was going to suggest several methods.

Comment: I tried but I still don't understand how to get only the name :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [MFC tutorial](http://courses.washington.edu/css450/2008.Fall/web_contents/from_students/450Hints/mfc_tutorial/tutorial_2.html) for adding a button to a dialog and what has to be done to "wire it up" so that clicking the button invokes an event handler for the BN_CLICKED event.

Inside the BN_CLICKED event handler (that is, the function that is called when you click the button), you'll want to launch the dialog that lets you selecte the file.  @Jongware suggested [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167922/how-to-make-choose-file-function-on-windows-programming), which has a couple of approaches.

Once the file has been selected and the dialog disappears, you'll have access to the string containing the selected file.  How you do this will depend on which approach you take in the preceding step.  Once you have the string, you can use the appropriate [File Management functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232(v=vs.85).aspx) to slice-and-dice the file name as necessary.

That's far short of the actual code you'll need to write, I know, but it should give you enough of a start to get going. HTH.

Comment: Ok made it! 
Thank's :)
Do you know how to make the interface more nice?
In Eclipse I used SetIcon and I knew the elements, but here I don't.
Do you also know the equivalent of button.Enable()/Disable() for Visual Studio?

Comment: In our MFC code, we do [`m_button.EnableWindow(FALSE)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kbfsahf.aspx) to disable it.  Of course, `m_button` is whatever you name your button.

Comment: @MarcoMontalto, as an aside, you'll find that MFC is quite antiquated when it comes to doing things, e.g., calling a function called `EnableWindow` instead of setting something like an `IsEnabled` property.  Here a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e.aspx) which might help.

Comment: Thank you Matt!
And you are right, MFC is not that good. There is no comparison with eclipse or jdeveloper.

Comment: Sometimes you don't have a choice; my legacy project is MFC-based.  All the new stuff we're doing is C#, though.  MUCH easier.